# what is the displacement of slider A

Tags: dynamics

[image][image][image]

It asks about the displacement of that particle

Comment: This looks like homework so you need to show your work or your question will be closed.

Comment: okay, i will upload it tomorrow.

Comment: Anybody else see a problem with b(i)?

Comment: I already update my work, the problem is the unstretched length and the height does not given

Comment: The length of the spring is not important.  The assumptions are the length is longer than the compression and the stiffness is the same for the amount of compression needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. What do you mean by the stiffness being the same? How to calculate if there are no any length is given?

Comment: For ease of discussion assume there is a little bit of friction so that it does come to rest and theta is 90. The equilibrium position will then be when the force in the springs equals the weight of the mass. hence mg=(k1+k2)x .

Comment: Free Body Diagram the mass.  What are all the forces acting on it? Hint: draw one for each spring, and at least two others.